# 2 problems number guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x

so as the title says i have 2 problems (that i know of) the first being when i type exit it as a number how would i verify it using is digit and print an error message the second being if i guess a number lets say 20 it will say too low then if i put 21 it will say too high 
here is the command prompt
 Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter exit to exit: 20 
Too low, try again
Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter exit to exit: 21 
Too high, try again

```
import random
guess = '0'
while (guess) != exit:
    answer = random.randrange(1,100)
    answer = str(answer)
    guess = input('Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter exit to exit: ')
    guess = (guess)
    if guess == answer:
        print('Correct')
    elif guess > answer :
        print('Too high, try again')
    elif guess < answer :
        print('Too low, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `isdigit`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
guess = '0'
while (guess) != exit:
    answer = random.randrange(1,100)
    answer = str(answer)
    guess = input('Enter a number between 1 and 100 or enter exit to exit: ')
    if not guess.isdigit(): 
        if guess == "exit":
            break
    guess = (guess)
    if guess == answer:
        print('Correct')
    elif guess > answer :
        print('Too high, try again')
    elif guess < answer :
        print('Too low, try again')
```